# React JS Sort by quantity > and < both return the same result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, indexof

This is my code:

```
const sortedDiscounts = discounts.sort((a, b) => a.quantity > b.quantity);
const amountSortedDiscounts = discounts
.map(el => el.quantity)
.concat(quantity + 0.5)
.sort((a, b) => a.quantity > b.quantity);
const amountSortedDiscounts2 = amountSortedDiscounts.sort(
(a, b) => a.quantity < b.quantity
);
const index = amountSortedDiscounts2.indexOf(quantity + 0.5) - 1;
```

Both amountSortedDiscounts and amountSortedDiscounts2 are the same, even tho' 1 is sorted by `a.quantity > b.quantity` and the latter is sorted by `a.quantity < b.quantity`

What am I doing wrong in the sort?

[image]

## EDIT:

This is what confused me:
This both return same order:

```
const sortedDiscounts = discounts.sort((a, b) => a.quantity > b.quantity);
const sortedDiscounts2 = discounts.sort((a, b) => a.quantity < b.quantity);
```

Trying to figure out why they are both the same

[image]

Comment: `a.quantity > b.quantity` that's not a valid sort compare function.

Comment: Also Array.sort, it doesn't copy the array first, you will want to clone the array then sort.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly

Comment: thanks, for numbers I understood, but have another question.
This: `const sortedDiscounts = discounts.sort((a, b) => a.quantity > b.quantity);` and this `const sortedDiscounts = discounts.sort((a, b) => a.quantity < b.quantity);` return the same array of objects also. why is that? Is it related to @Keith second comment?

Comment: @rosualin read the dupe I linked...

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Should I delete this question, if it is a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, otherwise your just console logging the same array, and the last array sorted is the one your seeing.  Try `const amountSortedDiscounts2 = amountSortedDiscounts.slice(0).sort(...`

Comment: Also, you are sorting THE SAME ARRAY twice. You don't have `discounts`, `sortedDiscounts`, and `sortedDiscounts2` - that's literally the exact same array given three different names. So when you print `sortedDiscounts` and `sortedDsciounts2`, they would have the exact same content every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is wrong compare.

ASC(ascending):

```
const sortedDiscounts = discounts.sort((a, b) => a.quantity - b.quantity);
```

DESC(descending):

```
const sortedDiscounts = discounts.sort((a, b) => b.quantity - a.quantity);
```

Comment: Thanks, getting the hang of this. I am testing now all cases and let you know if this works

Comment: @rosualin Keep in mind when you sorting the array, you are sorting the original array and storing to constant. I mean the sort will affect the original array. if you don't want to sort the original and just sort in sortedDiscounts then you can try this: `code: const sortedDiscounts = [...discounts].sort((a, b) => a.quantity - b.quantity); `

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with numbers, just use `a.quantity - b.quantity` instead.

See how sort works: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort